# How to add push-down/push-up effect when toggling "show" in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have made a drop-down menu using a combination of Javascript and CSS which is working great, but I would like a transition effect when the menu is shown and hidden, preferably a push-down one when the menu is being show, and a push-up one when it is being hidden... How do I integrate this? Thankyou.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  width: 80px;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.95;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  opacity: 1;
}
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Century Gothic, Calibri, Cambria, sans-serif;
}
.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}
.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <img onclick="myFunction()" src="../images/logotestme.png" class="dropbtn" </img>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com">Home</a>
    <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="http://www.coopertimewell.com/downloads">Downloads</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of toggling the display property by adding removing the show class,

you can, depending on what you want to achieve, animate the height, or top, or perhaps the transform property of the target element using css transition

here is a link to an example someone made demonstrating this:

http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gsFch

**code sample from that link:**

```
.sub-menu-parent {
  position: relative;
}
.sub-menu {
  visibility: hidden;
  /* hides sub-menu */
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(-2em);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s, visibility 0s linear 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.01s;
}
.sub-menu-parent:hover .sub-menu {
  visibility: visible;
  /* shows sub-menu */
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 1;
  transform: translateY(0%);
  transition-delay: 0s, 0s, 0.3s;
  /* this removes the transition delay so the menu will be visible while the other styles transition */
}
/* presentational */
body {
  padding: 2%;
  font: 18px/1.4 sans-serif;
}
nav a {
  color: #E00;
  display: block;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
}
nav a:hover {
  color: #F55;
}
nav ul,
nav ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
nav > ul {
  background: #EEE;
  text-align: center;
}
nav > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  border-left: solid 1px #aaa;
}
nav > ul > li:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.sub-menu {
  background: #DDD;
}
```